# Redirect output of mysqlsh interactive environment

Tags: bash, mysql

I'm trying to redirect the output of statements made **inside** the `mysqlsh` interactive environment.

I'm running mysqlsh inside the terminal on OSX and didn't find a proper parameter to achieve the rerouting in the help pages. Rerouting the output via the default "pipe grep > and_run.txt" doesn't work as the mysqlsh environment has it's own set of accepted commands.

My commands are:

```
:$ mysqlsh root@localhost:3306/my_schema
# now the mysqlsh interactive console is open with an active connection to my_schema
mysqlsh> shell.options.set('resultFormat','json')
mysqlsh> session.runSql("SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table")
# prints the schema as json array - i would like to rerout this output
```

Note: I moved this question over from SO as suggested by a helpful User there (thx @user1934428)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve my goal is to not use the "interactive-mode" of `mysqlsh` but open a new connection for each statement.

Not my preferred method as I guess that this initializes a new session for each command, but it works.

```
mysqlsh --uri root@localhost:3306/my_schema --sql --execute "select * from my_table;" --result-format=json/array > my_objects.json
```

I'd really be interested/thankful for a cleaner solution.